# Is there a way to make two blocks of code go one after the other

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a thing where I have a bunch of questions that are asked one after the other and I have a problem that I keep running into. When I do just one question it works very well but when I add another question this happens. I'm doing this in IDLE by the way.

```
Which of these is not a capital city of South Africa
What is the river that runs through London, England
```

Appears in the shell window, but both before it makes the buttons, so by the time the buttons appear your screen is loaded with a bunch of GUIs, and text. Why does it do this!

```
a = list()
print('Which of these is not a capital city of South Africa')
from time import sleep
sleep(5)
from tkinter import *
#The buttons are the possible answers
def bAaction():
    print('TRUE!')
    a.append(1)
    print('score')
    b = sum(a)
    print(b)
    window.destroy()
def bBaction():
    print('False')
    a.append(0)
    print('score')
    b = sum(a)
    print(b)
    window.destroy()
def bCaction():
    print('False')
    a.append(0)
    print('score')
    b = sum(a)
    print(b)
    window.destroy()
def bDaction():
    print('False')
    a.append(0)
    print('score')
    b = sum(a)
    print(b)
    window.destroy()
window = Tk()
buttonA = Button(window, text='Johannesburg', command=bAaction)
buttonB = Button(window, text='Bloemfontein', command=bBaction)
buttonC = Button(window, text='Cape Town', command=bCaction)
buttonD = Button(window, text='Pretoria', command=bDaction)
buttonA.pack()
buttonB.pack()
buttonC.pack()
buttonD.pack()
from time import sleep
sleep(5)
```

I then would have another question that's the same, but with different answers and a different question ect.

The expected output would be it to show a question with the possible answers and then wait 5 seconds.

If you know how? It would be great if you could explain to me how to make the second question wait until a button is pressed. Thanks for any help.

Comment: button should run function which answers for question and then it change text in buttons and labels, and doesn't destroy window. But it would need to keep questions and answers in list so it would be easier to get text and replace in buttons and labels.

Answer (score 0):

I create list `data` with dictionaries which have question, answers and which answer is correct.

And then I create window with empty Buttons and Labels and use function `set_next_question()` to get question for `data` and use it to set text in Buttons and Labels.

Buttons run functions which check if it is correct answer and run `set_next_question()` to get next question from `data` and use it to set text in Buttons and Labels. This way next question doesn't have to wait.

In `IDLE` you don't have to use `window.mainloop()` because `IDLE` is created with `tkinter` and it runs own  `window.mainloop()` but normally you have to use `window.mainloop()` to start your program.

```
import tkinter as tk

data = [
    {
        'question': 'Which of these is not a capital city of South Africa',
        'answers': ['Johannesburg', 'Bloemfontein', 'Cape Town', 'Pretoria'],
        'correct': 0 # 'Johannesburg'
    },
    {
        'question': 'What is the river that runs through London, England',
        'answers': ['Dunaj', 'Nil', 'Tamiza', 'Yellow River'],
        'correct': 2, # 'Tamiza'
    }
]

def buttonA_action():
    global score
    if current_question['correct'] == 0:
        score += 1
    label_score['text'] = 'score: {}'.format(score)
    set_next_question()

def buttonB_action():
    global score
    if current_question['correct'] == 1:
        score += 1
    label_score['text'] = 'score: {}'.format(score)
    set_next_question()

def buttonC_action():
    global score
    if current_question['correct'] == 2:
        score += 1
    label_score['text'] = 'score: {}'.format(score)
    set_next_question()

def buttonD_action():
    global score
    if current_question['correct'] == 3:
        score += 1
    label_score['text'] = 'score: {}'.format(score)
    set_next_question()

def set_next_question():
    global next_question_id
    global current_question

    if next_question_id >= len(data):
        print('end score:', score)
        window.destroy()
        quit()

    current_question = data[next_question_index]

    label_question['text'] = current_question['question']
    buttonA['text'] = current_question['answers'][0]
    buttonB['text'] = current_question['answers'][1]
    buttonC['text'] = current_question['answers'][2]
    buttonD['text'] = current_question['answers'][3]

    next_question_index += 1

# --- mian ---

next_question_index = 0 
current_question = None
score = 0

window = tk.Tk()

label_question = tk.Label(window, text='')
buttonA = tk.Button(window, text='', command=buttonA_action)
buttonB = tk.Button(window, text='', command=buttonB_action)
buttonC = tk.Button(window, text='', command=buttonC_action)
buttonD = tk.Button(window, text='', command=buttonD_action)
label_score = tk.Label(window, text='score: 0')

label_question.pack()
buttonA.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
buttonB.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
buttonC.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
buttonD.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
label_score.pack()

set_question()

window.mainloop()
```

---

By the way: button's actions are very similar - only one number is different in all functions - so they could use the same function with differentargument

```
def action(number):
    global score
    if current_question['correct'] == number:
        score += 1
    label_score['text'] = 'score: {}'.format(score)
    set_next_question()

def buttonA_action():
    action(0)

def buttonB_action():
    action(1)

def buttonC_action():
    action(2)

def buttonD_action():
    action(3)
```

Or even use `lambda` to assign to `command=` function with argument:

```
buttonA = tk.Button(window, text='', command=lambda:action(0))
buttonB = tk.Button(window, text='', command=lambda:action(0))
buttonC = tk.Button(window, text='', command=lambda:action(0))
buttonD = tk.Button(window, text='', command=lambda:action(0))
```